# TypeError: Cannot read property 'v4' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, typeerror, uuid

I am getting this error in Vue.js:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:628 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'v4'
of undefined"

found in

---> <AddTodo> at src/components/AddTodo.vue
   <App> at src/App.vue
     <Root>
```

I have already installed uuid, so v4 should be working, but it is not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the same error and I solved it.

```
import {v4} from 'uuid';

const uuId = v4()
```

Comment: thank you man, I don't know why but changing `import uuid from "uuid";` to `import { v4 } from "uuid";`  fixed my issue

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
import * as uuid from 'uuid';
```

Now you can call anything from uuid. Such as,

```
uuid.v4();
```